# Flex Combobox strange problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, combobox

I am facing a strange problem with the combobox in Flex. In the following code :

```
    public function rollCombo(cmb:ComboBox,value:String):void
    {
            if(value=='') return;
            var i:int=0;
            cmb.selectedIndex = 0;
            var dp1:XMLListCollection =   (XMLListCollection(cmb.dataProvider);
            trace(value);
            while(dp1[i]!=value && i<dp1.length)
              cmb.selectedIndex = ++i;
              cmb.validateNow();
              cmb.validateDisplayList();

            trace(cmb.selectedLabel);
    }
```

in an example case, at the end of the execution of the function, i is 7, and
cmb.selectedLabel is "xyz"(according to the trace output), but the label displayed
in the combobox is a different one.

Also, this is rather unpredictable. It happens sometimes and not always.

Answer (score 2):

The last selectedIndex is out of range, because you use pre-incrementation. Which means i becomes dp1.length before the test, and it's assigned to selectedIndex too. That might explain the weird behavior. You'll probably want to use post-incrementation.

Also. The only thing that gets executed in that while looks to be

```
cmb.selectedIndex = ++i;
```

I don't know if that's what you wanted, but you might need some "{}" there.